# How To DismissViewcontroller Segue From Main Viewcontroller Using Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am trying to fadeout or dismiss segue from main viewcontroller. For dismiss I need to mention `identifier` because it's a separate view controller.

`FYI :` I need to dismiss after plist data successfully written.

For show the segue viewcontroller I have used below

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"myCustomSegue" sender:self];
```

For Dismiss we can do easy but my question is how can we do by identifier?

Comment: Add more of your code????

Comment: Just I have added mainviewcontroller button click on another segue view controller. In mainviewcontroller once plist written success I want to dismiss newly added segue. For adding we are using above code but for dismiss we dont have syntax with identifier!@DilumN

Comment: I'm sure this **must** have been asked a gazillion times... (to lazy to search)

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is a "Present Modally" (or modal) segue, just use the following:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

It will dismiss whatever UIViewController subclass has been presented via your segue - it is therefore not necessary to "dismiss by identifier".

If it is a "Show" (or push") segue, then use:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```